# What's the single word to describe the smell of the perfume of someone who just walked by?

Tags: meaning, single-word-requests

I read the word sometime ago and can't remember it. 
the smell of the perfume of someone after he/she walks by..

Comment: "obnoxious", generally.

Comment: Probably something like "fragrance", or a more generic word such as "aura" or, better, "emanation".  A technical word would be "efflux".

Comment: @GraphicsResearch: Indeed, and frequently "pong" would fit as well. :-)

Comment: The word is "odor".

Comment: If you like it, it's a _fragrance_ or _aroma_. If it bothers you, it's an _odor_.

Comment: My brother and I always call it the "danger zone" :)

Answer (score 47):

The word is unsurprisingly from French: ***sillage***.

> Sillage (pronounced as see-yazh) is a term used to describe a scented trail left by the fragrance wearer. It comes from the French word for “wake,” as in the trail left in the sky by an airplane or on the water by a boat.  Sillage defines how fragrance diffuses around the wearer, and a strong sillage means that a fragrance projects well.
>
> <sup>http://boisdejasmin.com/2011/02/perfume-vocabulary-fragrance-terms-sillage.html</sup>

Though, *sillage* technically defines the degree of the scent of a perfume left behind also and it is a term used in perfumery jargon<sup>[1](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/us/definition/american_english/sillage)</sup>. There are different levels of *sillage* and there is even the term *monster sillage* to define the strongest fragrance trail. [This Elle article](http://www.elle.com/beauty/makeup-skin-care/the-fragrance-trail-how-to-find-your-perfect-perfume-610001) talks about *sillage* in detail.

<sub><sup>**1**</sup> [oxforddictionaries] *sillage* - the degree to which a perfume’s fragrance lingers in the air when worn</sub>

---

Additionally, ***wake***, ***slipstream*** or ***trail*** (of a perfume) is used also and they are more suitable for everyday or novelistic speech.

Examples:

> He started to mumble a phony apology when the **wake of her perfume** struck him like a strong whiskey.
>
> <sup>[The Stewards: A Fight to the Death of Animal Survival *by Robert Sherretta* (2010)]</sup>
>
> ---
>
> She returned the crystal bottle with the rubber squeeze ball and its silken tassel to her dresser, and grabbing her nutria jacket, she breezed out of the apartment,leaving us in the **trail of her perfume**.
>
> <sup>[Good-bye to the Mermaids: A Childhood Lost in Hitler's Berlin *by Karin Finell* - 2006]</sup>
>
> ---
>
> I followed behind her in the **slipstream of her perfume**, past a polished wooden staircase and into a long, wainscoted hallway.
>
> <sup>[The Last Heir: A Mystery *by Chuck Greaves* (2014)]</sup>

Comment: I'd love to beieve this, but it's not in Chambers, Collins, or the OED.

Comment: @TimLymington: Added more details. Is it convincing enough now? :)

Comment: I've smelled silage before and I wouldn't consider it perfume (unless you're a cow).

Comment: Do you think *sillage* is likely to be understood by readers outside the fragrance industry?

Comment: @NateEldredge: No. But it is the word and context is everything. I gave details in the answer also along with more understandable words.

Answer (score 14):

You may want the word ***waft*** as it carries the sense of the movement of air carrying the smell along:

It can be used as a verb:

> Pass or cause to pass easily or gently through or as if through the air.
>
> *The smell of perfume wafted out of the department store.*

or as a noun:

> A gentle movement of air.
>
> *I detected a waft of cheap perfume.*

Answer (score 6):

The word [**scent**](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/scent) could fit here, as it can be used to describe a (often pleasant) smell which fills the air as the result of someone or something.

For example, "as the woman passed by, we caught the scent of her perfume".

Comment: Mr. Pacino spent a whole movie focusing on [*The Scent of a Woman*](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0105323/)

Answer (score 4):

Some words that might describe it:

**Whiff** or **Fragrance**. Hope that helps.

Answer (score 2):

If you wish to connote that the smell is unpleasant, you could consider *miasma*, which the American Heritage Dictionary [defines as](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/miasma):

> 1. A noxious atmosphere or influence.
> 2. a. A poisonous atmosphere formerly thought to rise from swamps and putrid matter and cause disease.
>
>    b. A thick vaporous atmosphere or emanation

(Puns on "my asthma" are left as an exercise to the reader.)