# The presence of a person who has left a place

Tags: single-word-requests, word-choice, nouns

**Q:** What word should we use, if we were to describe the PRESENCE left behind, by a person after he/she leaves a place? [I have faced this exact situation a couple of times in the past few days,believe me!] (or) Can *sillage* be used in this situation? i.e in an abstract sense?

[Oxford Living Dictionaries](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/sillage) provide the following definition:

> (noun) The degree to which a perfume's fragrance lingers in the air when worn
>   *‘neither scent has a very strong sillage’*
>   (mass noun) *‘a summer fragrance with good sillage’*

The term  is generally used to describe the *fragrance* that continues to linger after a person has walked by, but can it also be used figuratively?

If you guys think 'sillage' can be used in an abstract sense, can you please provide a few examples?

**Q:** Is there a word that fits the description I described above?

Comment: Not a duplicate. Please read edited question. @Josh

Comment: The original question gives detailed answers about usage and meaning of sillage. As for its figurative usage, it is a question of personal opinion and style.

Comment: Is that usage acceptable?

Comment: Acceptable by whom?

Comment: There are, I believe,  better alternatives than *sillage*, to describe the presence (not the scent) left by a person. But you need to be more specific. Is the presence felt positive or negative? Anyway, I've reopened the question.

Comment: Thanks I'll edit the question again and try to be more specific.... @Mari-LouA

Comment: This is going to be a POB question at best. Still a duplicate though!

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/205810/whats-the-single-word-to-describe-the-smell-of-the-perfume-of-someone-who-just

Comment: @Josh  The OP is not asking about the fragrance, he is asking about the presence a person leaves behind in a room. He has repeatedly asked if *sillage* can be used figuratively. He probably means if there is an equivalent. Anyway, the OP edited the question, made it clearer, provided research. It ticks nearly all the SWR boxes. Questions for much less, that showed no effort, have been upvoted by the community.

Comment: I really appreciate the help @Mari-Lou A .. I have edited the title as well..

Answer (score 2):

There are many ways of saying what the question requires.

> Her *aura* dominated the committee long after she had left for Moscow.

Her personality had influenced the committee  despite her absence.

> Her *presence* was obvious in the House decades after her death.

Her memory, for whatever reason, survived her death

> Her *tenor* flavored the meeting long after her departure.

Whatever she had done, or been, during the meeting remained somewhat after her departure.

> She left an *atmosphere* of reason that sobered the mob into inaction.

Her deportment had caused the mob to be more reflective and less  reactive, perhaps.

If a single, generic word is required to satisfy the question, then I think *aura* would be it. A number of terms might be used in specific situations: *mood*, *feeling*, *ambience*, *climate*, *complexion*, for example.